# How to get particular html div tags from a HTML page source?

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping, screen, web-scraping

Im using Asp.net and C# and im able to get the source code of a HTML page using webrequest and webresponse in a text file, now i want to get only some elements or html tags instead of whole source code, can any 1 help me in this?? and if possible can we save the elements and values in a mysql database. Suggest if any useful reference links??

Comment: To be able to answer this question, you'll need to provide examples of what you need to extract from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @ thanks Daniel A White, but im new in this part and confused of using HTML Agility pack is their a possibility of getting direct code or simple code that i can use directly with asp.net i have very short time to work on this...

Answer (score -2):

You would need to match the HTML with regular expressions then save the results to a desired location.

See: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx

Comment: While it is true you cannot use regular expressions to correctly *parse* HTML, they are a *excellent* tool to extract known elements from well-formed HTML.

Answer (score -4):

here is an entire tutorial on that but the link provides the topic you are currently asking, there should be some examples too

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmldiv.php

```
<div id="menu" align="right" >
<a href="">HOME</a> | 
<a href="">CONTACT</a> | 
<a href="">ABOUT</a> |
<a href="">LINKS</a>
</div>

<div id="content" align="left" >
<h5>Content Articles</h5>
<p>This paragraph would be your content
 paragraph with all of your readable material.</p>
<h5 >Content Article Number Two</h5>
<p>Here's another content article right here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the OP's question